# isAuthorized() Exception: Can not close file with id 0 because it is still in use

Tags: config, orientdb

I **upgraded** Orientdb from 2.0.16 to **2.2.4**.

In 2.0.16 all is fine(databases run and login in browser is working). But now not in 2.2.4. There I get this one in the log:

> 2016-07-10 20:59:41:942 WARNI {db=OSystem} MBean with name
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations:id=1899654914,name="OSystem",type=OAtomicOperationsMangerMXBean
>   has already registered. Probably your system was not shutdown
>   correctly or you have several running applications which use OrientDB
>   engine inside [OAtomicOperationsManager] 2016-07-10 20:59:41:944 SEVER
>   isAuthorized() Exception: Can not close file with id 0 because it is
>   still in use
>           DB name="OSystem" [OSystemUserAuthenticator]

So I tried to run it locally on my Windows machine. I just downloaded the whole folder and then startet *server.bat*. And it works without any error.

So why on an Ubuntu it throws that error? And why it works with the same folder on a Windows machine? I did not change anything except the memory settings, that need to be lower on the Ubuntu machine.

### When I try to start server.sh today...

I get this one:

`````
 sh /home/ubuntu/orientdb/bin/server.sh
           .
          .`        `
          ,      `:.
         `,`    ,:`
         .,.   :,,
         .,,  ,,,
    .    .,.:::::  ````                                 :::::::::     :::::::::
    ,`   .::,,,,::.,,,,,,`;;                      .:    ::::::::::    :::    :::
    `,.  ::,,,,,,,:.,,.`  `                       .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
     ,,:,:,,,,,,,,::.   `        `         ``     .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
      ,,:.,,,,,,,,,: `::, ,,   ::,::`   : :,::`  ::::   :::      :::  :::    :::
       ,:,,,,,,,,,,::,:   ,,  :.    :   ::    :   .:    :::      :::  :::::::
        :,,,,,,,,,,:,::   ,,  :      :  :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::::::::
  `     :,,,,,,,,,,:,::,  ,, .::::::::  :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
  `,...,,:,,,,,,,,,: .:,. ,, ,,         :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
    .,,,,::,,,,,,,:  `: , ,,  :     `   :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
      ...,::,,,,::.. `:  .,,  :,    :   :     :   .:    :::::::::::   :::     :::
           ,::::,,,. `:   ,,   :::::    :     :   .:    :::::::::     ::::::::::
           ,,:` `,,.
          ,,,    .,`
         ,,.     `,                                          GRAPH DATABASE
       ``        `.
                 ``                                          orientdb.com
                 `
removing old pid file /home/ubuntu/orientdb/bin/orient.pid

2016-07-13 21:06:28:451 INFO  Loading configuration from: /home/ubuntu/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2016-07-13 21:06:29:355 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.4 (build 2.2.x@rf5282664db9300ef3358fb4d7e2066ad418c2e61; 2016-07-08 12:30:59+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2016-07-13 21:06:29:372 INFO  Databases directory: /home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases [OServer]Error during initialization of engine 'plocal', engine will be removed
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make member of class com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl accessible:  module jdk.management does not export com.sun.management.internal to unnamed module @41e68d87
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.throwInaccessibleObjectException(java.base@9-internal/Reflection.java:420)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(java.base@9-internal/AccessibleObject.java:174)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:189)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:183)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.util.OMemory.getPhysicalMemorySize(OMemory.java:65)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaultDiskCacheSize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:80)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaults(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:63)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.initialize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:52)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.startup(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:56)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:872)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:480)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:167)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:342)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Error during engine shutdown
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.shutdown(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:112)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:878)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:480)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:167)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:342)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on opening database 'plocal:/home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases/OSystem'
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:187)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:342)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on opening database: the engine 'plocal' was unable to start. URL was: plocal:/home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases/OSystem. Registered engines was: [memory, remote, plocal]
        DB name="plocal:/home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases/OSystem"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:481)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:167)
        ... 6 more
`````

So there should not be another Java process... and this never happenend to me in the old version. And what is the OSystem good for? I don't know why it is created. Maybe this is the reason for my issue?

I'm now not even able to start the server. I always get the same message. When I run `shutdown.sh` I get `pid file detected, killing process`. I'm out of ideas except downgrading =/

### ...and sometimes I get...

`````
 sh /home/ubuntu/orientdb/bin/server.sh
           .
          .`        `
          ,      `:.
         `,`    ,:`
         .,.   :,,
         .,,  ,,,
    .    .,.:::::  ````                                 :::::::::     :::::::::
    ,`   .::,,,,::.,,,,,,`;;                      .:    ::::::::::    :::    :::
    `,.  ::,,,,,,,:.,,.`  `                       .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
     ,,:,:,,,,,,,,::.   `        `         ``     .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
      ,,:.,,,,,,,,,: `::, ,,   ::,::`   : :,::`  ::::   :::      :::  :::    :::
       ,:,,,,,,,,,,::,:   ,,  :.    :   ::    :   .:    :::      :::  :::::::
        :,,,,,,,,,,:,::   ,,  :      :  :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::::::::
  `     :,,,,,,,,,,:,::,  ,, .::::::::  :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
  `,...,,:,,,,,,,,,: .:,. ,, ,,         :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
    .,,,,::,,,,,,,:  `: , ,,  :     `   :     :   .:    :::      :::  :::     :::
      ...,::,,,,::.. `:  .,,  :,    :   :     :   .:    :::::::::::   :::     :::
           ,::::,,,. `:   ,,   :::::    :     :   .:    :::::::::     ::::::::::
           ,,:` `,,.
          ,,,    .,`
         ,,.     `,                                          GRAPH DATABASE
       ``        `.
                 ``                                          orientdb.com
                 `

2016-07-13 21:14:57:687 INFO  Loading configuration from: /home/ubuntu/orientdb/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2016-07-13 21:14:58:821 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.2.4 (build 2.2.x@rf5282664db9300ef3358fb4d7e2066ad418c2e61; 2016-07-08 12:30:59+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2016-07-13 21:14:58:858 INFO  Databases directory: /home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases [OServer]Error during initialization of engine 'plocal', engine will be removed
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make member of class com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl accessible:  module jdk.management does not export com.sun.management.internal to unnamed module @41e68d87
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.throwInaccessibleObjectException(java.base@9-internal/Reflection.java:420)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(java.base@9-internal/AccessibleObject.java:174)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:189)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(java.base@9-internal/Method.java:183)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.util.OMemory.getPhysicalMemorySize(OMemory.java:65)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaultDiskCacheSize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:80)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.configureDefaults(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:63)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.initialize(OMemoryAndLocalPaginatedEnginesInitializer.java:52)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.startup(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:56)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:872)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:480)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:167)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:342)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Error during engine shutdown
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.engine.local.OEngineLocalPaginated.shutdown(OEngineLocalPaginated.java:112)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.startEngine(Orient.java:878)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:480)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:167)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:342)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on opening database 'plocal:/home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases/OSystem'
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:187)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:148)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.init(OSystemDatabase.java:151)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OSystemDatabase.<init>(OSystemDatabase.java:44)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.initSystemDatabase(OServer.java:1227)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:342)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServerMain.main(OServerMain.java:41)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on opening database: the engine 'plocal' was unable to start. URL was: plocal:/home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases/OSystem. Registered engines was: [memory, remote, plocal]
        DB name="plocal:/home/ubuntu/orientdb/databases/OSystem"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient.loadStorage(Orient.java:481)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.<init>(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:167)
        ... 6 more
`````

### Now I tried to downgrade JDK9 to JDK8

It downgraded  to JDK 8...

```
root:~# sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
root:~# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-0ubuntu4~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
root:~# javac -version
javac 9-internal
```

but still the same errors...

```
2016-07-15 14:53:48:347 WARNI {db=OSystem} MBean with name com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.atomicoperations:id=954836302,name="OSystem",type=OAtomicOperationsMangerMXBean has already registered. Probably your system was not shutdown correctly or you have several running applications which use OrientDB engine inside [OAtomicOperationsManager]
2016-07-15 14:53:48:359 SEVER isAuthorized() Exception: Can not close file with id 0 because it is still in use
        DB name="OSystem" [OSystemUserAuthenticator]
```

### Maybe my JAVA_HOME is wrong?

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
# sudo update-alternatives --config java
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart the server after be sure no other servers/consoles were running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes for sure. I shutdowned via shutdown.sh till there was no remaining instance. That startet new one via server.sh. All fine just that I get the message like above.

Comment: Whenever I have seen this happen, it's because of an OrientDB Java process still running.  You might ps aux | grep java (or equivalent) and see if something is runnning, just in case.  Also, as Luca suggested, you might restart the actual physical server (or VM), then see if it will start/stop properly with server.sh/shutdown.sh.

Comment: I'm not able to kill the java Process. I don't know:
`root:~# ps aux | grep java
root     28818  0.0  0.1  14224   940 pts/0    S+   21:01   0:00 grep --color=auto java`

Comment: Hi do you run server under JDK 9 ?

Comment: root:~#java -version
`openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)`
root:~# javac -version
`javac 9-internal`. So I would say yes. Is this a problem?

Comment: Actually yes. We are not compatible , yet

Comment: Okay damnit. I gonna try a JDK downgrade however this is done :)

Comment: Please let us know how it goes and so I will be able to put the answer.

Comment: It's now downgraded to JDK8. But still the same error.

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make member of class com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl accessible:  module jdk.management does not export com.sun.management.internal to unnamed module @41e68d87
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.throwInaccessibleObjectException(java.base@9-internal/Reflection.java:420) ??

Comment: Where do you see that? Let's go into Chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117415/discussion-between-kwoxer-and-andrey-lomakin).

Comment: Could you feel in an issue, it will be much easier to discuss it?

Comment: Okay openend at: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6426

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6426). So the solution is pretty simple. Just set some settings in the `server.sh`:

```
if [ -z "$ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY" ] ; then
    ORIENTDB_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms64m -Xmx128m"
fi

if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS_SCRIPT" ] ; then
    JAVA_OPTS_SCRIPT="-Djna.nosys=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=200g -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Drhino.opt.level=9"
fi

# ORIENTDB SETTINGS LIKE DISKCACHE, ETC
if [ -z "$ORIENTDB_SETTINGS" ]; then
    ORIENTDB_SETTINGS="-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=128 -Dmemory.chunk.size=33554432"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here with the same problem, was able to fix it by uninstalling java9 and installing java8 instead. Here are the steps I followed.

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-jdk
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have both installed. But I use the version 8. But it's not working. Do you really think that uninstalling Java 9 could fix my issue anyways?

Comment: I bet your path is set to version 9 still. Did you do `java -version`?

Comment: java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: I think for me it's another issue. You can find some more info here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6426 It's really bad that since 5 months or so I cannot use OrientDB anymore... =/

Comment: I happened with any software upgrade. But I don't know which it was and when it axactly happenened.

Comment: So mine was from a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 fully upgraded.

Comment: Solved it with settings in the server.sh as you can see in my answer. Anyway thanks for your idea tho it did not help me :)